# Onclick button running automatically after $() insertion

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm 99% through done writing this code but I'm stuck on the last hurdle.

The main issue here is:
I have 2 HTML buttons which aim to change text based on the function output, successful or not.
Currently, the logic for the functions is working - ie the expected returned values are as expected.
However, when I try to move these functions into my HTML file, they  automatically run, which is overwriting the default value and defeating the point of having the button.

Button:

```
<button id="goldButton" onclick = "${calcGoldTierStatus(exampleCustomer)}">Click me!</button> 
    <h2 id="goldResult">Gold tier eligibility:${goldTierEligible}</h2>
```

Function earlier in same script.js:

```
function calcSilverTierStatus() {
  if (
    exampleCustomer.previousStays >= silverTier.previousStays &&
    exampleCustomer.bookingAgencyId === null || String || Number &&
    (exampleCustomer.roomSpend / (exampleCustomer.roomSpend.length+=1)) >= 100 &&
    exampleCustomer.reservationNights >= silverTier.previousStays
  ) {
    silverTierEligible = ("Silver Eligibility:Eligible for Silver tier!")
  } else {
    silverTierEligible= ("Silver Eligibility:Not eligible for Silver Tier")
  }
}
```

What may be noteworthy is that I am passing the values into HTML via declaring a const 'content', then using:

`document.body.innerHTML = content;`

to write the HTML body.
It seems to be the `$(calcGoldTierStatus(exampleCustomer)}` that is causing the autorun, but I had no idea how to otherwise move the function into HTML from JS.

Comment: Why is your button onclick in that format? Why not just `onclick="calcGoldTierStatus(exampleCustomer)"` - and actually why are you passing a static parameter in there? You could easily reference that parameter in the function - I don't understand why `"${calcGoldTierStatus(exampleCustomer)}"` would automatically fire, but I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with that notation anyways...

Comment: it's in this format because I'm aiming to pass the function into the click part of the button within the HTML, I'm using ${} to bring the value in there - the scenario I have includes always using that particular parameter in this case

Comment: Yes, but still, why the template literal format? If you try `onclick="calcGoldTierStatus(exampleCustomer)"` does it clear the issue?

Comment: unfortunately it gives me a syntax error saying I haven't declared the function 'calcGoldTierStatus' when I don't use the literal, is there a way I can have the function saved directly in the HTML so it doesn't need the $() to be used?

Comment: if it helps, the exact error I get when I try to directly use the function without $() is:
loyalty-check.html:64 Uncaught ReferenceError: calcGoldTierStatus is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (loyalty-check.html:64)

Comment: I tried to move the function directly into a script tag in the HTML but it then started throwing various errors because it lacked the dependencies that the function required. I moved all necessary over for one function and I still get a syntax error of:
exampleCustomer is not defined
when I have defined exampleCustomer in script.js & directly in the HTML via importing the class
```
<script type="module">
      import exampleCustomer from "./script.js";
 </script>
```
- I did put these outside the 'body' of the HTML - since the body is going to be overwritten.

Answer (score -1):

I found from some posts that it is bad practice to use template literals inside onclick buttons. Instead, using a combination of event listeners, `getElementById`, and appending a HTML article object instead of replacing main, solved most my problems.

@me for a look at the exact ways I got around this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).